# Performance testing single page application components

Tags: angularjs, performance, benchmarking

We have an Angular single page application that loads fairly fast.  However, there are data components in the application that load (and render) asynchronously.  I've looked all over the web and it seems like a fairly common problem, but without a good solution.  Are there any tools out there that can perf benchmark just a component of a page, rather than the entire page?  And we need to know the time between the request made for data and when rendering that data is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the open source Chrome plugin Angular-performance, you can benchmark specific controllers, digest time and events in Angular applications: https://github.com/Linkurious/angular-performance

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of getting a reference to that particular view?

Similar to React + Flux, I believe Angular would be classified as a "current-state" front-end framework. Because it's functional programming and not object oriented. This is the reason company's have in the past switched over to angular, because of the speed and asynchronous nature of javascript.

If there are certain elements you don't want the DOM to render until conditions are met, I would recommend looking into *ng-show* and *ng-hide.*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

I hope that helps? I am not sure what situation in particular you don't want rendering asynchronously? Let me know how I can help.

Comment: The other thing you could look into is nested views using ui-router. Then set one view to ng-hide, and the nested view you want "perf benchmarked" to basically just do its natural thing.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, we do want rendering asynchronously.  But we need to be able to benchmark each component separately to ensure that each one loads within spec.